# Necessary and sufficient conditions for a right triangle

Tags: geometry

> Show that if for $\triangle ABC$ the equalities $h_c^2=a_1b_1$ and $b^2=b_1c$ are true where $h_c$ is the height, $AC=b, AB=c$ and $a_1$ and $b_1$ are the the projections of $BC$ and $AC$ on $AB$, then the triangle is right angled.

I want to demonstrate that together the conditions are sufficient without using the Law of Cosines or the Pythagorean theorem. The relations **in a right triangle** that we have studied and can use in the problem: $h_c^2=a_1b_1, a^2=ca_1$ and $b^2=cb_1$ where $BC=a, AC=b, AB=c$ and $a_1$ and $b_1$ are the projections of $AC$ and $BC$ on $AB$.

Counterexample:

[image]

$\triangle ABC$ $(AC<BC)$ is right triangle and then $h^2=a_1b_1$. Let $M$ lie on $BH$ and $HM=AH=b_1$. For $\triangle MBC$ $h^2=a_1b_1$ but it is NOT A RIGHT TRIANGLE.

Comment: Yes, SEPARATELY they are not sufficient conditions. They are necessary, but not sufficient.

Comment: I think I made it clear now. I want to demonstrate that together they are sufficient without using the Law of Cosines or the Pythagorean theorem. I can only use $h_c^2=a_1b_1, a^2=ca_1$ and  $b^2=cb_1$.

Comment: I just wrote the relations in a right triangle that we have studied and can use in the problem.

Comment: Everything is fine in the post!

Comment: No, it doesn't. $h_c^2=a_1b_1$ is not a sufficient condition for a triangle to be right. See the post.

Comment: Yes, I do have a counterexample.

Comment: Added in the post.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova: Ah ... Obtuse angle at $A$. That *is* problematic. (The equal complementary angles may not get *added*, but may be *subtracted*.) Good thinking. :)  I'll delete my comments to avoid confusion.

Comment: It's all right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your example gives the key for proving the statement.

Indeed if one assumes that $H $ is an internal point of $AB$ the proof that $\angle ACB$ is right angle trivially follows from $h_c^2=a_1b_1$ in view of similarity of the right triangles $AHC$ and $CHB$ and the fact that two complimentary angles *add* at the vertex $C$.

Thus the triangle $ABC$ can be not right-angled only if $H$ is not an internal point of $AB$. This is however impossible due to the condition $b^2=b_1c$. To prove this assume that the point $H $ is not internal. Let $A'$ be the image of $A$ upon reflection over the altitude $CH$. Since the point $H$ is an internal point of the segment $A'B $, $\angle A'CB $ is right angle, as was shown above. Therefore:
$$A'C^2=A'H\cdot A'B\implies 
b^2=b_1(a_1+b_1).$$

Together with the assumption 
$$b^2=b_1c=b_1|a_1-b_1|$$ 
this however implies that at least one of $a_1,b_1$ is $0$ which contradicts to the assumption $h_c^2=a_1b_1$.

Observe that it is possible to perform the above proof also in the opposite order (i.e. start with the assumption $b^2=b_1c$ and continue with $c^2_h=a_1b_1$). The common idea is: if $H$ is an internal point of $AB$ any of the conditions $a^2=a_1c$, $b^2=b_1c$, $c^2_h=a_1b_1$ *alone* is sufficient for the proof. And if any two of the three conditions are satisfied the point $H$ have to be internal.

Answer (score 1):

**First Solution**:

It's known that a triangle is right angled if and only if the three edges satisfies the Pythagorean theorem (this statement follows from the [Low of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)). So we have only to verify the Pythagorean theorem for the triangle.

Named $a=BC$ we have:
\begin{gather}
a^2+b^2 = h_c^2 + a_1^2 + b_1 c = a_1b_1 + a_1^2 + b_1c=\\
a_1(b_1+a_1) + b_1 c = a_1c+b_1c=(a_1+b_1)c = c^2 
\end{gather}
Where the first equality follows from Pythagorean theorem $a^2=h_c^2+a_1^2$, and we have used that $a_1+b_1=c$ because they are the projections.

---

**Second solution**:

Take a cartesian plane and put the triangle $ABC$ in it: $A=(-a_1,0)$, $B=(b_1,0)$, $C=(0,h_c)$.

Now take the line $AC$ and $CB$. Their angular coefficients are rispectively
\begin{gather}
AC:\quad \frac{h_c-0}{0-(-a_1)} = \frac{h_c}{a_1}\\
CB:\quad \frac{h_c-0}{0-b_1} = -\frac{h_c}{b_1}
\end{gather}

Multipling now the angular coefficients we obtain:
$$
\frac{h_c}{a_1} \cdot \left( - \frac{h_c}{b_1}\right) = \frac{h_c^2}{a_1b_1} = -1
$$
So the two lines are perpendicular and the angle in $C$ is a right angle.

Edit: I realize now that these arguments work for the angle in $A$ and $B$ acute.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I can't use the the Pythagorean theorem for this problem.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova added a new solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have that $h_c^2=a_1b_1, a^2=ca_1$ and $b^2=cb_1$ then $a^2b^2=c^2h_c^2=4A_{\triangle ABC}^2$. Thus, $A_{\triangle ABC}=\frac{ab}{2}$ and $a$ is perpendicular to $b$.

Comment: $a^2=ca_1 $ is not given.